# Change object to float or numeric in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
snkr = pd.read_csv('StockX-Data-Contest-2019-3.csv')
```

This is the link for the data: https://www.kaggle.com/hudsonstuck/stockx-data-contest

```
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0   Order_Date    99956 non-null  object 
 1   Brand         99956 non-null  object 
 2   Sneaker_Name  99956 non-null  object 
 3   Sale_Price    99956 non-null  object 
 4   Retail_Price  99956 non-null  object 
 5   Release_Date  99956 non-null  object 
 6   Shoe_Size     99956 non-null  float64
 7   Buyer_Region  99956 non-null  object
```

I have read in this dataset called snkr,

I would like to change the price to float or numeric and the date to date. But I have tried these so far, and none seems to work.

```
snkr["Sale_Price"] = snkr.Sale_Price.astype(float)
snkr["Sale_Price"]=snkr.Sale_Price.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
snkr['Sale_Price'] = snkr['Sale_Price'].map(lambda x: float(x))
snkr['Sale_Price'] = pd.to_numeric(snkr['Sale_Price'],errors='coerce')
for i in range(0, len(snkr.Sale_Price)):
    snkr.iloc[:,i] = pd.to_numeric(snkr.iloc[:,i], errors='ignore')
snkr['Sale_Price'] = pd.to_numeric(snkr['Sale_Price'])
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: .as type : ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$1,097 '

conver_objects: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'convert_objects'

Comment: so replace that `'$'` sign then typecast it....i.e `snkr['Sale_Price']=snkr['Sale_Price'].str.replace('$','').astype(float)`

Comment: It still shows the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,097 '

Comment: then replace `','` as well `snkr['Sale_Price']=snkr['Sale_Price'].str.replace('$|,','').astype(float)`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm still getting the same error ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$1097 '

Comment: try: `snkr['Sale_Price']=snkr['Sale_Price'].replace('$|,','',regex=True).astype(float)`

Comment: It's still not working, same error again

Comment: I found this chunk of code works, but it changed everything to NaN. 
snkr['Sale_Price'] = pd.to_numeric(snkr['Sale_Price'],errors='coerce')